# Compressing Video file

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with compressing video using FFmpeg.But what I want is delete the file after compressing. Also compressing is not working.
Below is my code what I have tried so far.

```
int compressedFile = await _flutterFFmpeg
        .executeWithArguments(["-i", file.path, "-c:v", "mpeg4", 'compressed'+file.path]);
    print(compressedFile);
```